# How to append an increasing number to a dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a new dictionary based on an existing dict: In this new dict I want to append an increasing integer to the end of each value. My dict has several keys but repetead values.

I'm using the following code has an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
list_1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
list_2 = ["a","a","b","b","c","c"]

dict = dict(zip(list_1,list_2))

another_dict = {}
counter = 0
for keys in dict.keys():
    if dict[keys] == "a" :
        counter += 1
        another_dict[keys] = "a_" + str(counter)
    if dict[keys] == "b":
        counter += 1
        another_dict[keys] = "b_" + str(counter)
    if dict[keys] == "c":
        counter += 1
        another_dict[keys] = "c_" + str(counter)

print(another_dict)
```

and I'm getting this result

***{40: 'b_1', 10: 'a_2', 50: 'c_3', 20: 'a_4', 60: 'c_5', 30: 'b_6'}***

when I would like to get

***{40: 'b_1', 10: 'a_2', 50: 'c_1', 20: 'a_1', 60: 'c_2', 30: 'b_2'}.***

The dict order isn't important.
Thank you for your help.
Kind Regards.
Ivo

Comment: As a side note, don't call your dictionary `dict`, or you'll never be able to call the `dict` constructor again for the rest of the script.

Comment: Thank you for pointed that out. Kind Regards. Ivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
another_dict = {}
counters = {}
for key,value in dict.items():
    counter = counters.get(value, 0) + 1
    counters[value] = counter
    another_dict[key] = "%s_%d" % (value, counter)
```

`counters` keeps track of the count for each value.  If it's not initialized, it starts at zero (thanks to the dictionary `.get()` call).

Answer (score 2):

You need a different counter for each of the different values.

Comment: There are only three different values in the example, not seven (despite the text description), so I think it's clearer to just leave the number "seven" out. If you disagree, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: After read your comment I changed the post to make it more clear. Thank you for your help. Kind Regards.Ivo